# How do I center a form within Jumbotron - Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm completely new to Bootstrap so sorry if this is a silly question.

I am trying to center a form within a jumbotron:
Everything in the jumbotron centers except the form. I've been a this for hours and just cant figure it out.
Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <style type="text/css">
          .jumbotron{
              text-align: center;
          }
      
 </style>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-3">Hello, world!</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
  <form class="form-inline">
   <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Name</label> <input class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="Jane Doe" type="text"> <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Username</label>
   <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
     @
    </div><input class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Username" type="text">
   </div>
   <div class="form-check mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
    <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
   </div><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All it really needs is a set width and an auto `margin`.

```
width: 700px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

However, you can also use bootstrap rows and columns if you wish.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will this be viewed on mobile screens? If so 700px will cause the form to be greater in width than the screen size. Using a Bootstrap `col-*-*` will utilize % widths ensuring it doesn't overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has a class [.center-block](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#less-mixins-centering) that can be used alongside a nested `col-*-*` sizing to center the form. The responsive `col-*-*` will help the form adjust based on screen size.

A set `width` could cause the form to flow out of the container at smaller screen size.

You will also need to remove the `float:left;` from the inner `col-*-*` which you can set via a class:

CSS:

```
.pull-none {
  float: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 foo">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 center-block pull-none bar">
                        <form></form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also, use `col-*-offset-*` to center elements as well, here is an example setting the form to `col-sm-6` and offsetting by `4` to center:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 foo">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4 center-block pull-none bar">
            <form></form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xg2pd4qz/3/) demonstrating the functionality.